# Suppose we roll a pair of dice twice. What is the probability that the pair of numbers obtained in both attempts is the same

Tags: probability, statistics

There was a similar question asked, but it considered the sum of dice pairs, in my question i am asking about the numbers on the dices in the second roll should be same as the first roll. Assume that both the dices are distinguishable.

Thanks,
Mrinal

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 2):

If dice are different, i.e. the outcome is `green 3, red 3`, then the probability is exactly $1/36$ since you must duplicate the roll exactly.

**UPDATE**

On your follow-up question, if on the first roll you get `green 1, red 5` then to duplicate this, on the second roll you would need to roll `green 1, red 5` again. Assuming the dice are independent, you have $1$ favorable outcome of $6 \time 6=36$ possible outcomes, so a probability of success of $1/36$.

Comment: Not that there's a huge difference, but I think he's saying the two numbers are to be the same, but not necessarily on the same die as before.

Comment: @scoopfaze just to make sure, changed to $(3,3)$ instead

Comment: I upvoted. Hopefully OP responds/edits his question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. Just to clarify more. For e.g. if on the first roll we get {1,5} then whats the probability we get {1,5} on the second roll too. So far i have managed to just calculate the sample space, which would be (36*36)